# Extract Powerpoint chart Min and Max values

Tags: excel, vba, automation, powerpoint, vba7

I am trying to create a VBA code which can help me open a presentation, go to each slide, check for a chart and then copy its min and max value in an excel sheet. I have a 40+ slides presentation with multiple chart and this code will help me to check if the axis values in all the chart are consistent.
Below is the code I am working on. So far, able to open the presentation but not able to open the chart and copy the values to excel. Please help, new to VBA coding

```
Sub CopySlidechart()

    Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim ppPlaceHolder As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim oRow As Long

    Set ppApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    ppApp.Visible = msoTrue
    
    Dim input_path As String
    input_path = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")

    Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Open(input_path)

    oRow = 6
    For Each ppSlide In ppPres.Slides
        For Each ppPlaceHolder In ppSlide.Shapes
            If ppPlaceHolder.HasChart Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(oRow, "B").Value = ChartObject.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(oRow, "C").Value = ChartObject.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale
    oRow = oRow + 1
                oRow = oRow + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next ppPlaceHolder
    Next ppSlide

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. There is no `ChartObject` in Powerpoint, only a `Chart` (which is similar to `ChartObject.Chart` in Excel). Note that you need to check for `Axes(xlValue)` as you want to read min and max from the y-Axis.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 
oRow = 6
For Each ppSlide In ppPres.Slides
    For Each ppPlaceHolder In ppSlide.Shapes
        If ppPlaceHolder.HasChart Then
            Dim chart as Chart, axis as Axis
            Set chart = ppPlaceHolder.Chart
            Set axis = chart.Axes(xlValue)

            ws.Range(oRow, "B").Value = axis.MaximumScale
            ws.Range(oRow, "C").Value = axis.MinimumScale
            oRow = oRow + 1
        End If
    Next ppPlaceHolder
Next ppSlide
```